# What are the Disciplines?

Tags: the-magicians

The Disciplines I know of are physical, psychic, and knowledge, but I don't know what the others are, or what they mean (knowledge *magic*?). I also don't know if 'summoning' is a discipline or not, but the symbol for it appeared on Quentin's hand, and I don't know what discipline he is.

What are they, what do they deal with, and what are some of their attributes. I am looking for in-depth answers not just ones that simply name the Disciplines.

Comment: http://themagicians.wikia.com/wiki/Disciplines

Comment: http://www.penguin.com/read/book-clubs/the-magicians/9781101079423

Comment: The first link just names them, but does not fully answer my question, and the second link does not answer my question besides telling that Quentin's nondescript discipline is an intended mystery.

Comment: Hence why I didn't post them as **answers**, merely as comments.

Answer (score 3):

The Disciplines are;

#### Physical

Physical magic deals with manipulating the forms of matter and energy, essentially allowing them to make the laws of physics their bitch. In D&D terms, they’re sorcerers. Their magic interacts with the world at a subatomic level.

#### Knowledge

Knowledge has a toe dipped in each pool of magic, they are drawn body and mind  to magic. Knowledge disciples are scholars, they study magic in all its forms. In D&D terms, they’re wizards.

#### Natural

Natural is pretty straight forward, it’s nature magic. They’re the druids of the school.

#### Illusion

Illusion is also straight forward, they create various illusions that can trick all five senses.

#### Healing

Healing disciples are sort of your clerics, their magic heals body, mind, and soul.

#### Psychic

Lastly, you have your psychics, they deal with the mind.